# Exception when creating a Databricks cluster via REST API

Tags: powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I can successfully create a Databricks cluster via REST API using the following in Postman:

```
POST /api/2.0/clusters/create HTTP/1.1
Host: adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.azuredatabricks.net
Authorization: Bearer eyJ <REMOVED> EJA
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "cluster_name": "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xx-x-xxx-##-xxxxxxx-####",
  "spark_version": "5.5.x-scala2.11",
  "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
  "autoscale" : {
    "min_workers": 2,
    "max_workers": 10
  },
  "autotermination_minutes": 30
}
```

When I convert the above for use with PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod, I get a WebException. When running the script in the Windows PowerShell ISE (running as Administrator) the following results:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 91
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

The Azure AD token generated in PowerShell is the same token used successfully in Postman. This issue doesn't appear to be related to a bad token.

Here is the PowerShell that results in the exception:

```
<SCRIPT>

... API calls re: AAD Token omitted ...

Write-Host "Create Databricks Cluster"

$body = @{
    cluster_name = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xx-x-xxx-##-xxxxxxx-####"
    spark_version = "5.5.x-scala2.11"
    node_type_id = "Standard_DS3_v2"
    autoscale = @{
        min_workers = 2
        max_workers = 10
    }
    autotermination_minutes = 30
}

$headers = @{
    "Authorization"="Bearer " + "$apiKey";
    "Content-Type"="application/json";
}

$uri = "$uriroot/2.0/clusters/create"

Write-Host $uri
Write-Host $headers

try { $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body }
catch { 
    Write-Host $_
    Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
    Write-Host $_.Exception
    Write-Host $_.ErrorDetails
}

Write-Host $response

</SCRIPT>
```

What is the PowerShell version missing but present in Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I found. Use `ConvertTo-Json` on the `$body` variable passed to the `-Body` command-line argument.

```
try { $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) }
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer until the 48 hour window expires...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Please do remember to accept it after 48 hours.